# how to add data in sql database with datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

heres my code in adding data to sql database

```
Dim ConStr As String = "Data Source=SYSTEMS-LAPTOP\DEVSQL;Initial Catalog=ContactDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd123"
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM dataContactDB"
Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection
Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
Dim sqlAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim sqlBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
Dim sqlDataset As DataSet
Dim sqlTable As DataTable
```

this code loads my data in datagridview from sqldatabase

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
    sqlCon.Open()
    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon)
    sqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
    sqlBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter)
    sqlDataset = New DataSet
    sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDataset, "dataContactDB")
    sqlTable = sqlDataset.Tables("dataContactDB")
    sqlCon.Close()
    dgData.DataSource = sqlDataset.Tables("dataContactDB")
    dgData.ReadOnly = True
    dgData.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
End Sub
```

my codes in adding data to sqldatabase

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    sqlCon.Open()
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "insert into dataContactDB(con_Name,con_Phone,Address,Company,Gender) values('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtPhone.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & txtCompany.Text & "','" & txtGender.Text & "')"
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlCon.Close()

End Sub
```

all i want to do is when you add data in sqldatabase. datagridview will retrieve the new added data and add it on its list. every time i add data . datagridview didnt show my recent added data, how do i do that?

Comment: call `frmMain_Load` after adding it to the databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to reload the data in grid. Put all code the in a function named LoadMyGrid, that you have written in frm_load. Now call this method from frm_load. Also call same method in your button click event in the last line.

Comment: hey sir Muhammad Idrees, thanks for your instruction. it relly works. i tried sir Amey's instruction, it didht work. 

thanks to all sir . it realy helps me. Good day!!!

Comment: Not actually, he also suggested the same kind of thing. I just put some more details to make it easier.

Comment: thanks by the way, it really helps me. i have also new concerns. can you help me?

Comment: here is my new concern. i want to update data

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369173/how-to-update-data-from-datagridview-with-sqldatabse-in-vb-net