# how to update data from datagridview with sqldatabse in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, sql-update, sql-insert

i use another form editting data. when i double click the selected row in datagridview it will transfer the data in another form(frmEdit). i use this codes but it seems not working, how can i fix this. please help.

```
Dim queryEdit As String = String.Empty
    queryEdit = "update dataContactDB set con_Name=@Name, con_Phone=@Phone, Address=@Address, Company=@Company, Gender=@Gender.text where con_Phone=txtPhone.text"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbFunction.db)
        Using comm As New SqlCommand
            With comm
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = queryEdit

                  ---- is there a error in this part? ------
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", txtCompany.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtGender.Text)

            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                loadmyGrid()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using[![my error screenshot][1]][1]
```

Comment: Not get cleared. You are saying that you want to edit data directly from gridview, but in code you are getting values from textboxes. Do you want to edit in the same way you did Insert, means from textboxes ?

Comment: the code is not about editing but inserting and is a little messy... the parameters are useless because in the query there are no parameters at all (eg they are filled, passed to the command and the command totally ignores them), just a string concatenation (EVIL!). what did you try so far for editing?

Comment: i have long codes, im sorry. what i want to do now is after adding data and datagridview will refresh its content from sqldatabase. i have to edit the selected row from datagridview

Comment: Have ou already extracted the selected row values from gridview in textboxes ?

Comment: For updating You have to use `update dataContactDB set con_Name='some value', .... where some_field = some_value;`. You need some condition to know which record will be updated. Like @Paolo wrote, Your code isn't about editing (updating) but adding new record (inserting). It would be nice to add one more field for `id`. What if You have two persons with same name or what ever You will use for condition (`where filed=value;`).

Comment: i can now transfer data from datagridview row to my textboxes. how ca i edit its data??

Comment: i try to use update code but ins not working